# Recursive query with sub-graph aggregation

Tags: recursion, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use Neo4j to write a query that aggregates quantities along a particular sub-graph.

We have two stores `Store1` and `Store2` one with supplier `S1` the other with supplier `S2`. We move 100 units from `Store1` into `Store3` and 200 units from `Store2` to `Store3`.

We then move 100 units from `Store3` to `Store4`. So now `Store4` has 100 units and  approximately 33 originated from supplier `S1` and 66 from supplier `S2`.

[image]

I need the query to effectively return this information, E.g.

> S1, 33
>   S2, 66

I have a recursive query to aggregate all the movements along each path

```
MATCH p=(store1:Store)-[m:MOVE_TO*]->(store2:Store { Name: 'Store4'}) 
RETURN store1.Supplier, reduce(amount = 0, n IN relationships(p) | amount + n.Quantity) AS reduction
```

**Returns:**

| store1.Supplier  | reduction|
|-------------------- |-------------|
| S1               | 200      |
| S2               | 300      |
| null             | 100      |

**Desired:**

| store1.Supplier  | reduction|
|---------------------|-------------|
| S1               | 33.33     |
| S2               | 66.67     |

Comment: Do you add a relationship between stores every time you move inventory? 
if so then you'd query the aggregation of the relationship properties ?

Comment: We add a `MOVE_TO` relationship every time we move inventory. I can query the aggregation of the relationship properties, but need to sum those at each level i think

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but nothing in your graph actually indicates how many of the 100 units moved to store 4 were moved from store 1 or store 2 originally. Are you assuming it's always in proportion to the percentages moved to store 3? If so, I think that you need to reverse the question by computing the "weight" of each branch starting from store 4 and following the relationships in reverse.

Comment: @Pat the assumption is correct, the amount moved from each store to store4 is proportional to their contribution to store3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this one :

```
MATCH (s:Store) WHERE s.name = 'Store4'
MATCH (s)<-[t:MOVE_TO]-()<-[r:MOVE_TO]-(supp)
WITH t.qty as total, collect(r) as movements
WITH total, movements, reduce(totalSupplier = 0, r IN movements | totalSupplier + r.qty) as supCount
UNWIND movements as movement
RETURN startNode(movement).name as supplier, round(100.0*movement.qty/supCount) as pct
```

Which returns :

```
supplier    pct
Store1  33
Store2  67
Returned 2 rows in 151 ms
```

Comment: That works, thanks for your answer. Would you know what indexes I need to add to maximise performance?

Comment: for this query, an index on store names are required. if store names are unique then this should be a unique constraint.

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite this query for a graph of arbitary depth?

Comment: I asked a separate question for the arbitrary depth query here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060104/recursive-query-with-sub-graph-aggregation-arbitrary-depth

Answer (score 3):

So the following is pretty ugly, but it works for the example you've given.

```
MATCH (s4:Store { Name:'Store4' })<-[r1:MOVE_TO]-(s3:Store)<-[r2:MOVE_TO*]-(s:Store) 
WITH s3, r1.Quantity as Factor, SUM(REDUCE(amount = 0, r IN r2 | amount + r.Quantity)) AS Total
MATCH (s3)<-[r1:MOVE_TO*]-(s:Store) 
WITH s.Supplier as Supplier, REDUCE(amount = 0, r IN r1 | amount + r.Quantity) AS Quantity, Factor, Total 
RETURN Supplier, Quantity, Total, toFloat(Quantity) / toFloat(Total) * Factor as Proportion
```

I'm sure it can be improved.

Comment: I voted +1 for your attempt. just that you complicate some parts. but good stuff btw.

Comment: I asked a separate question for the arbitrary depth query here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060104/recursive-query-with-sub-graph-aggregation-arbitrary-depth