# Recursive query with sub-graph aggregation (arbitrary depth)

Tags: recursion, neo4j, cypher

I asked a question [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036055/recursive-query-with-sub-graph-aggreagation) about aggregating quantities along a graph. The two answers provided worked well, but now I am trying to extend the Cypher query it to a graph of variable depth.

To summarize we start of with a bunch of leaf stores which all are associated with a particular supplier, which is a property on the `Store` node. Inventory is then moved along to other stores and the proportion from each supplier corresponds to their contribution to the original store.

So for node `B02`, `S2` contributed `750/1250 = 60%` and `S3` contributed `40%`. We then move 600 units our of `B02` of which `60%` belongs to `S2` and `40%` to `S3` and so on.

[image]

What we want to know what percentage of the final 700 units into `D01` belong to each supplier. Where suppliers with the same name are the same supplier. So for the above graph we expect:

> S1, 38.09
>   S2, 27.61
>   S3, 34.28

I've prepared a graph using this Cypher script:

```
CREATE (A01:Store {Name: 'A01', Supplier: 'S1'})
CREATE (A02:Store {Name: 'A02', Supplier: 'S1'})
CREATE (A03:Store {Name: 'A03', Supplier: 'S2'})
CREATE (A04:Store {Name: 'A04', Supplier: 'S3'})
CREATE (A05:Store {Name: 'A05', Supplier: 'S1'})
CREATE (A06:Store {Name: 'A06', Supplier: 'S1'})
CREATE (A07:Store {Name: 'A07', Supplier: 'S2'})
CREATE (A08:Store {Name: 'A08', Supplier: 'S3'})

CREATE (B01:Store {Name: 'B01'})
CREATE (B02:Store {Name: 'B02'})
CREATE (B03:Store {Name: 'B03'})
CREATE (B04:Store {Name: 'B04'})

CREATE (C01:Store {Name: 'C01'})
CREATE (C02:Store {Name: 'C02'})

CREATE (D01:Store {Name: 'D01'})

CREATE (A01)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 750}]->(B01)
CREATE (A02)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 500}]->(B01)
CREATE (A03)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 750}]->(B02)
CREATE (A04)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 500}]->(B02)
CREATE (A05)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 100}]->(B03)
CREATE (A06)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 200}]->(B03)
CREATE (A07)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 50}]->(B04)
CREATE (A08)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 450}]->(B04)

CREATE (B01)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 400}]->(C01)
CREATE (B02)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 600}]->(C01)
CREATE (B03)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 100}]->(C02)
CREATE (B04)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 200}]->(C02)

CREATE (C01)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 500}]->(D01)
CREATE (C02)-[:MOVE_TO {Quantity: 200}]->(D01)
```

The current query is this:

```
MATCH (s:Store { Name:'D01' })
MATCH (s)<-[t:MOVE_TO]-()<-[r:MOVE_TO]-(supp)
WITH t.Quantity as total, collect(r) as movements
WITH total, movements, reduce(totalSupplier = 0, r IN movements | totalSupplier + r.Quantity) as supCount
UNWIND movements as movement
RETURN startNode(movement).Supplier as Supplier, round(100.0*movement.Quantity/supCount) as pct
```

I am trying to use recursive relationships, something along the lines of this:

```
MATCH (s)<-[t:MOVE_TO]-()<-[r:MOVE_TO*]-(supp)
```

however that gives multiple paths to the end node and I need to aggregate the inventory at each node I think.

Comment: I'm thinking about this, though the problem is that I don't think cypher really does recursion.  Cypher evaluates one subgraph at a time with it's `MATCH`, which in this case is one path across the depth of the tree.  But you want to compare the paths against each other

Comment: Also, if you just want the paths from the store to the original supplier nodes you'd want something like `MATCH (target:Store {Name:'D01'})<-[r:MOVE_TO*]-(source:Store) WHERE source.Supplier IS NOT NULL`

Comment: In addition to Brians's suggestion, similarly you can use `WHERE NOT (source)<-[:MOVE_TO]-()`

Comment: I have added an answer that shows how to correctly calculate the answer (for an arbitrary graph that has the same model). It involves an iterative query, which is the only way to get the right results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query generates the correct results for any arbitrary graph that conforms to the model described in the question. (When `Store` x moves merchandise to `Store` y, it is assumed that the `Supplier` percentages of the moved merchandise is the same as for `Store` x.)

However, this solution does not consist of just a single Cypher query (since that may not be possible). Instead, it involves multiple queries, one of which must be iterated until the calculations cascade through the entire graph of `Store` nodes. That iterated query will clearly tell you when to stop iterating. The other Cypher queries are needed to: prepare the graph for iteration, report the Supplier percentages for the "end" node(s), and clean up the graph (so that it is restored to the way it was before step 1, below).

These queries could probably be further optimized.

Here are the required steps:

1. Prepare the graph for the iterative query (initializes the temporary `pcts` array for all starting `Store` nodes). This includes the creation of a singleton `Suppliers` node that has an array with all the supplier names. This is used to establish the order of the elements of the temporary `pcts` arrays, and to map those elements back to the correct supplier name.

   ```
   MATCH (store:Store)
   WHERE HAS (store.Supplier)
   WITH COLLECT(store) AS stores, COLLECT(DISTINCT store.Supplier) AS csup
   CREATE (sups:Suppliers { names: csup })
   WITH stores, sups
   UNWIND stores AS store
   SET store.pcts =
     EXTRACT(i IN RANGE(0,LENGTH(sups.names)-1,1) |
       CASE WHEN store.Supplier = sups.names[i] THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)
   RETURN store.Name, store.Supplier, store.pcts;
   ```

   Here is the result with the question's data:

   ```
   +---------------------------------------------+
   | store.Name | store.Supplier | store.pcts    |
   +---------------------------------------------+
   | "A01"      | "S1"           | [1.0,0.0,0.0] |
   | "A02"      | "S1"           | [1.0,0.0,0.0] |
   | "A03"      | "S2"           | [0.0,1.0,0.0] |
   | "A04"      | "S3"           | [0.0,0.0,1.0] |
   | "A05"      | "S1"           | [1.0,0.0,0.0] |
   | "A06"      | "S1"           | [1.0,0.0,0.0] |
   | "A07"      | "S2"           | [0.0,1.0,0.0] |
   | "A08"      | "S3"           | [0.0,0.0,1.0] |
   +---------------------------------------------+
   8 rows
   83 ms
   Nodes created: 1
   Properties set: 9
   ```
2. Iterative query (run repeatedly until 0 rows are returned)

   ```
   MATCH p=(s1:Store)-[m:MOVE_TO]->(s2:Store)
   WHERE HAS(s1.pcts) AND NOT HAS(s2.pcts)
   SET s2.pcts = EXTRACT(i IN RANGE(1,LENGTH(s1.pcts),1) | 0)
   WITH s2, COLLECT(p) AS ps
   WITH s2, ps, REDUCE(s=0, p IN ps | s + HEAD(RELATIONSHIPS(p)).Quantity) AS total
   FOREACH(p IN ps |
     SET HEAD(RELATIONSHIPS(p)).pcts = EXTRACT(parentPct IN HEAD(NODES(p)).pcts | parentPct * HEAD(RELATIONSHIPS(p)).Quantity / total)
   )
   FOREACH(p IN ps |
     SET s2.pcts = EXTRACT(i IN RANGE(0,LENGTH(s2.pcts)-1,1) | s2.pcts[i] + HEAD(RELATIONSHIPS(p)).pcts[i])
   )
   RETURN s2.Name, s2.pcts, total, EXTRACT(p IN ps | HEAD(RELATIONSHIPS(p)).pcts) AS rel_pcts;
   ```

   Iteration 1 result:

   ```
   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | s2.Name | s2.pcts       | total | rel_pcts                                                    |
   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | "B04"   | [0.0,0.1,0.9] | 500   | [[0.0,0.1,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.9]]                               |
   | "B01"   | [1.0,0.0,0.0] | 1250  | [[0.6,0.0,0.0],[0.4,0.0,0.0]]                               |
   | "B03"   | [1.0,0.0,0.0] | 300   | [[0.3333333333333333,0.0,0.0],[0.6666666666666666,0.0,0.0]] |
   | "B02"   | [0.0,0.6,0.4] | 1250  | [[0.0,0.6,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.4]]                               |
   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   4 rows
   288 ms
   Properties set: 24
   ```

   Iteration 2 result:

   ```
   +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | s2.Name | s2.pcts                                      | total | rel_pcts                                                     |
   +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | "C02"   | [0.3333333333333333,0.06666666666666667,0.6] | 300   | [[0.3333333333333333,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.06666666666666667,0.6]] |
   | "C01"   | [0.4,0.36,0.24]                              | 1000  | [[0.4,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.36,0.24]]                              |
   +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   2 rows
   193 ms
   Properties set: 12
   ```

   Iteration 3 result:

   ```
   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | s2.Name | s2.pcts                                                       | total | rel_pcts                                                                                                                    |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | "D01"   | [0.38095238095238093,0.27619047619047615,0.34285714285714286] | 700   | [[0.2857142857142857,0.2571428571428571,0.17142857142857143],[0.09523809523809522,0.01904761904761905,0.17142857142857143]] |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   1 row
   40 ms
   Properties set: 6
   ```

   Iteration 4 result:

   ```
   +--------------------------------------+
   | s2.Name | s2.pcts | total | rel_pcts |
   +--------------------------------------+
   +--------------------------------------+
   0 rows
   69 ms
   ```
3. List the non-zero `Supplier` percentages for the ending `Store` node(s).

   ```
   MATCH (store:Store), (sups:Suppliers)
   WHERE NOT (store:Store)-[:MOVE_TO]->(:Store) AND HAS(store.pcts)
   RETURN store.Name, [i IN RANGE(0,LENGTH(sups.names)-1,1) WHERE store.pcts[i] > 0 | {supplier: sups.names[i], pct: store.pcts[i] * 100}] AS pcts;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | store.Name | pcts                                                                                                                |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | "D01"      | [{supplier=S1, pct=38.095238095238095},{supplier=S2, pct=27.619047619047617},{supplier=S3, pct=34.285714285714285}] |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   1 row
   293 ms
   ```
4. Clean up (remove all the temporary `pcts` props and the `Suppliers` node).

   ```
   MATCH (s:Store), (sups:Suppliers)
   OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[m:MOVE_TO]-()
   REMOVE m.pcts, s.pcts
   DELETE sups;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   0 rows
   203 ms
   +-------------------+
   | No data returned. |
   +-------------------+
   Properties set: 29
   Nodes deleted: 1
   ```

Comment: Thanks @cubersam, this query gets the right result. I had the wrong expected result in the question. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Done, I thought SO automatically did it

Answer (score 3):

As i said before i enjoyed this question. I know you already accepted an answer, but I decided to post my final response as it also returns the percentile without client effort ( which means you can also do a SET on the nodes to update the value in the db when you need to ) and of course if for any other reason as one i can come back to :)
here is the link to the [console example](http://console.neo4j.org/r/rys9k8)

it returns a row with the store name, sum moved to it from all suppliers and  the percentile of each supplier

```
MATCH p =s<-[:MOVE_TO*]-sup
WHERE HAS (sup.Supplier) AND NOT HAS (s.Supplier)
WITH s,sup,reduce(totalSupplier = 0, r IN relationships(p)| totalSupplier + r.Quantity) AS TotalAmountMoved
WITH sum(TotalAmountMoved) AS sumMoved, collect(DISTINCT ([sup.Supplier, TotalAmountMoved])) AS MyDataPart1,s
WITH reduce(b=[], c IN MyDataPart1| b +[{ Supplier: c[0], Quantity: c[1], Percentile: ((c[1]*1.00))/(sumMoved*1.00)*100.00 }]) AS MyData, s, sumMoved
RETURN s.Name, sumMoved, MyData
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is this generalized?  Would it still work if there was one more level?

Comment: this should work with as many levels as you'd like. Of course you could also limit it to store or supplier, by adding the filter to the s or sup match

Comment: Unfortunately, the math used by this query is incorrect. The actual  calculation for the final percentages does not involve adding all the quantities in each path to `D01`, and then using the grand total as the denominator for the percentage calculations. Instead, you have to calculate the percentages at each Store node, and then multiply together the appropriate percentages along each path. I will be creating an answer that generates the right answer (but it requires iterative calls).

Answer (score 2):

I can't think my way through a solution in pure cypher because I don't think you can do recursion like this in cypher.  You can use cypher to return you all of the data in the tree in a simple way so that you can compute it in your favorite programming language, however.  Something like this:

```
MATCH path=(source:Store)-[move:MOVE_TO*]->(target:Store {Name: 'D01'})
WHERE source.Supplier IS NOT NULL
RETURN
  source.Supplier,
  reduce(a=[], move IN relationships(path)| a + [{id: ID(move), Quantity: move.Quantity}])
```

This will return you the id and the quantity for each of the relationships along each path.  Then you could process that client-side (perhaps first converting it into a nested data structure?)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I like your technique for accumulating the movements into the array. I might wait a bit longer to see if there is other answers.

Comment: Fair enough ;)  I'd definitely like to see another answer.  Also, I don't know what language you're using, but I should mention if you're using java or something that integrates with java APIs, you could alternatively access your database through the neo4j java APIs.  You would need to operate in embedded mode, though, which has it's own complications.

Comment: We are using C# so ideally we'd like to avoid writing any java code